# Is it possible to make the `is` attribute dynamic?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

Let's have two dummy CustomElements

```
customElements.define("span-red", class extends HTMLSpanElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.style.color = "red";
    }
}, { extends: "span" }
);

customElements.define("span-blue", class extends HTMLSpanElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.style.color = "blue";
    }
}, { extends: "span" }
);
```

Now having this HTML

```
<span is="span-red">Red</span>
<span is="span-blue">Blue</span>
```

I want to render *Red* in blue color by setting it's `is` attribute to `span-blue`.

There is no pure native solution, [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-core-concepts) is pretty clear about this:

> After a custom element is created, changing the value of the is attribute does not change the element's behavior, as it is saved on the element as its is value.

There is a way to set their `observedAttributes` property and move the functionality to `attributeChangedCallback` method, but this doesn't change the class, of course.

The only way I figured out was to take the outerHTML of the Element, change the `is` in the string and re-create the element. Doing it this way, all references to the element and its event listeners are lost. Unless I track them manually, but this way is really cumbersome and non-native.

I'd like to have something like this

```
customElements.define("span-red", class extends HTMLSpanElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        decorate();
    }
    destruct() { ... }
    decorate() { ... }
    ...
}, { extends: "span" }
);
```

Where the `decorate()` resets the Element to its original state (HTMLSpanElement), then change the prototype and call `decorate()` of the new prototype (span-blue in this case).

If this vision is impossible, then more generally - is it possible to make the `is` attribute dynamic?

Comment: So both constructors would share like a lot, right? Why use the `is` attribute exactly? Sounds like the usual flow would rather be to define a custom element and set an attribute on that, e.g `<colored-span color="red">`, and have a single constructor handle that.

Comment: @Kaiido That is *autonomous custom element*. In this case, I need *customized built-in element* sharing common constructor, but having completely different complex behaviour, which can be switched just by setting `is` value. Imagine `<input is="input-number">` producing plus and minus buttons next to the input, and `<input is="input-slider">` producing customized slider. Both require js/css and html manipulation to work, and after `is` is dynamic, all the work can be set/unset just by changing `is` value in any way (including code inspector). I have working example already.

Comment: Well I'm not sure that's what you need actually. That really sounds like an hack. For the <input> case, why don't you extend over the `type` attribute? <input is=jan-input type=range> vs <input is=jan-input type=number>? Added benefits: you keep all the semantics intact, visitors with JS disabled still have *something*, etc.

Comment: @Kaiido  there are multiple ways to visualize inputs with the same type. To see how it is supposed to work, see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zv7cp48a/) (won't work on Safari). But yes - as I look at it, the same functionality can be done with MutationObserver on designated data attribute. On the other hand, enhancing such elements (incl. the dynamically loaded ones) would have to be done explicitly. The `onConnectedCallback` simplifies things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After some efforts, I managed to implement this. The issue was that `attributeChangedCallback` is called also upon creation (with oldVal set to null), so the `decorate` method had to be moved from constructor to `connectedCallback`.

Now it seems that `is` attribute is finally dynamic if all Custom Elements are built in this manner:

```
customElements.define("span-red", class extends HTMLSpanElement {
    constructor() { super(); }
    connectedCallback() { this.decorate(); }
    disconnectedCallback() { this.destruct(); }

    destruct() { this.style.removeProperty("color"); }
    decorate() { this.style.color = "red"; }

    static observedAttributes = ["is"]
    attributeChangedCallback(att, oldVal, newVal) {
        if(oldVal === null) return;
        if(att=="is") {
            this.destruct();
            if(newVal) {
                // TODO: handle if newVal is not defined in customElements
                this.prototype = new (customElements.get(newVal));
                this.prototype.decorate.call(this);
            }
        }
    }
}, { extends: "span" }
);
```

See the demo (with some issues solved) [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zv7cp48a/).

Comment: But this doesn't and will never work in Safari. Because Apple, since 2016, has firmly stated they will never implement _Customized_Built-In Elements_ because of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (Which Google, in Custom Elements V0, forgot when they threw _Customized Built In Elements_ against the wall to see if it would stick) Note: And every developer who skipped those classes (ehm I mean Classes) in uni

Comment: TL;DR: Its the L in SOLID Software Engineering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman This is living standard. Safari is abandoning standards like IE did. And we all know how IE with 90%+ market share ended.

Comment: I don't know about your use cases, in my cases it boils down to customers querying sites from their devices. For our restaurant thats 70% traffic from iPhones here in Amsterdam. IE eventually lost marketshare to a better FireFox and later Chrome. I don't see those iPhones being replaced with something better yet

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman luckily we target scanners with Android. The destruct/decorate pattern can be used on *Autonomous Custom Elements*, too (by observing some data attribute) and with little extra work (like attaching internals for form elements) equivalent functionality can be probably achieved, but it beats the semantics.

Comment: Why a data attribute? Doesn't ``is`` behave like any observed attribute on Autonomous Elements? ``<colored-span is="red">``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman true, but then then there would be additional behavior from browsers that does support Customized Built-In Elements. If the support for it is divided, then it is better avoid using `is` for cross-browser apps.

Comment: ``<colored-span>`` can never be(come) a Customized Built In Element. so the ``is`` attribute is actually the safest (standard) attribute to (ab)use, because, like you, most developers will avoid using it... because it is defined as "standard"... and thus UNUSED in apps that need to run in Safari.  ``<svg-icon is="hamburger">`` is (pun intended) in all my apps